# php sorted array and readfile not reading in order

Tags: php

I am trying to write a php function to save and then display comments on an article.

In my save.php, I am formulating the file with:
`$file = "article1/comments/file".time().".txt";`

Then using fwrite() to write to a directory.

In my index I have:

```
if ($handle = opendir('article1/comments')) {
  while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
      $files = array($file);
      sort($files);
      foreach($files as $comments){
        echo "<div class='message'>";
        readfile('article1/comments/'.$comments);
        echo "</div>";
      }
    }
  }
  closedir($handle);
}
```

For the most part this displays the comments in the correct order, but for some reason, some files are displaying out of order.  Furthermore, if I change sort() to rsort(), there is no change in how they are displayed.

I presume this is because readfile() is not following the sorted array's order.  So I am wondering for one, why readfile does not display the files in order from newest to oldest, and two, how can I make it display them correctly?

Thanks.

edit:  I copied the directory of comments from the live site to my local xampp installation, and the comments are displayed in order locally, but using the same code on my site results in comments not being in order.

Comment: What are you sorting?  the `$files` array will only ever have one element in it, so the sort is useless...  If you wanted the sort, you need to add `$file` to the `$files` array (`$files[] = $file`), and move the `foreach` loop and the `sort`  outside of the `while` loop...

Comment: @ircmaxell: That makes sense.  I am very new to php, so I am not quite sure how to do all of that.  I am trying to create an array containing all the files within a directory, then use readfile to display the contents of each file in order based on the file name.

Comment: Are you completely sure you cannot use any sort of database?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I can use SQL databases. Would that be a better way to do this?  This my first php project, so I am basically figuring it out as I go along

Comment: it would be thousands times better. To store both articles and comments in the database would be obvious and widely used solution. However, you can use files for learning purpose. It's always good to have basic filesystem skills

Comment: out of curiosity, what are the advantages of using a database?

Comment: a lot. reliablilty. SQL is a small data manipulation language. with only one short sentence you can accomplish a task which will require a screen of code in case of files. How would you delete a comment for example? All comments from same user? make a top of most commented articles?

Comment: hmm, interesting. I use a database with my RoR site, but I'm not too familiar with advanced SQL queries.  I've been meaning to check out cakePHP, maybe I will give that a try for this purpose.  thanks

Comment: lol. cake is not a database nor Rails is. It's just object interfaces to SQL, and pure SQL better to be learned first. By the way, you don't need complex queries for these tasks.

Comment: well, i know neither framework is itself a database, but both include tools to handle database management...but your're right, it would be better to learn SQL further than to rely on a framework to do much of the backend work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $files = array();

if ($handle = opendir('article1/comments')) {
  while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
       $files[] = $file; //adding file to array
    }
  }
  closedir($handle);
}
//if array is not empty-check (can go here)
if(count($files)>0) { 

 sort($files);

 foreach($files as $comments){
        echo "<div class='message'>";
        readfile('article1/comments'.$comments);
        echo "</div>";
      }//~foreach
}//~if
```

Comment: That works! It prepends "string(18) "file1288655842.txt" " above each file's output, however,

Comment: If you use above code, make sure to move sort($files); one line above foreach(). It will be a lot cheaper :)

Comment: so you are. why to make "minor" changes only? why not to correct obvious errors?

Comment: enough...i'll make the changes :)

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel:  I used glob and that is working perfectly, thanks. ---im not sure how to go about marking your comment as the solution here, however

Comment: @andreas: I'm accepting this as the final answer since it works and solves the problem, thanks--   foreach (glob("article1/comments/*.txt") as $filename) {
            echo "<div class='message'>";
            readfile($filename);
            echo "</div>"; --    is what I ended up using

Comment: Col. Shrapnel gave you a good tip for using the glob() function - so also keep that in mind also.

Comment: Yes, that is what i actually used. I voted for his comment as a "great comment". I do not know how to mark comments as solutions, and did not want to leave this question unmarked, though

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php), make sure to check [1st comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.isfile.php#76768) for DirectoryIterator's isFile() method, it should be enough to solve this question.

Answer (score 0):

Please, use any database for this stuff! Don't use files! This is not realy secure and has low performance

Comment: Where does a database store it's data?

Comment: Differs what sort of database you use) There are many databased except mysql (redis, memcache, mongo etc). Also, mysql in most cases store indexes in memory, so, sorting and filtering works much more faster than simple file-based DB

Comment: Your OS always stores filesystem indexes in memory. Honestly, to the certain level, files aren't THAT bad in terms if performance.

Comment: Can you please explain why files are inherently not secure?  Sure, you could implement them securely, but I would think you can secure them more than a database since there's no need to hit the network stack (and hence one less potential point of compromise).  But I'm quite curious to know how it's less secure and less performant in general (especially considering that databases are built on top of files)...